# Determine the boundedness of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I determine whether {$\frac{z}{1+z^2}$; z $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ \ {-i, i}} is bounded? My textbook is very poor at describing boundedness for complex functions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you find an $M$ such that $\lvert z/(z^2+1)\rvert\leq M$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm i\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going along with the hints,  you can look where the bad behavior might be happening, and see what happens as you approach it.  Dividing by 0 is generally bad, and getting near that tends to be explosive....so let's approach $i$ in nice, simple way.   Consider the sequence $x_n=\frac n {n+1} i$. You can see that the limit approaches $i$, but no point is $i$ so every point is in your domain.  Now lets see what your function does to the sequence.

$$f(x_n)=\frac {\frac n {n+1} i} {1+(\frac n {n+1}i)^2}$$
Multipling the top and bottom by $(n+1)^2$, we get 
$$f(x_n)=\frac {n(n+1)i}{(n+1)^2-n^2}=\frac {n(n+1)}{2n+1}i$$
Now, taking the norm, since the norm is multiplicative and the norm of $i$ is 1, we get $\| f(x_n)\|=\frac {n(n+1)}{2n+1}$, which grows without bound, hence this function is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can help is turning complex numbers into real numbers by using the modulus. For instance, $|1+z^2|\leq 1+|z|^2$ by the triangle inequality. Does this help as a beginning hint?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** What happens with $\frac{z}{1+z^2}$ when $z$ is very close to $i$?